# Push pull legs routine, what do you think of this?

Tags: workout-routines, strength-training, hypertrophy, muscle-endurance

I would like to post my routine I'm  on and see what you think. I have a few goals in mind and I've ironed out this routine over the years  with a few big setbacks ( knee surgery from a child hood injury never fixed and elbow surgery due to a torn triceps tendon I didn't let heal) before my surgery I was doing 5x5 stronglift program a b day. I was up to about 350 squat,  285 bench,  and 385 deadlift, 165 ovhd, and about 225 b.o.r. I was also cardio and skill training  with Muay Thai and Jujitsu.  I felt during that program that I was starting to cheat my form to get that extra 5 on the bar. Squats  were questionably parallel and using more and more lower back. Bench was okay but stalled several times, deadlift was great, overhead press I never  had great gains. I also felt fat and lazy.  My goal after elbow surgery was to start light again, perfect my form, rehab and focus on both  strength training and higher rep training to compliment MMA goals.  My squats I now go as low as possible for this reason and I now mix one or two heavy 3x5 or 5x5 sets with auxiliary  lifts at 2 or 3 x10-12. I also switched  to a push pull legs routine. Here is where I am at right now:

I am 5'4" 170 fight at 145lbs
Push:
3x5 flat bench 280lbs about stalled here AMRAP last set,
3x10-12Ovhd press seated (my ceiling  is super low!) 135,
2x 10-12Incline flys 45lbs,
2x 10-12 Flat flys 45lbs,
2x10 weighted dips 75lbs 1 set no weight AMRAP,
2x10 dumbbell pullover,
3x10-12 dumbbell skull crushers 20lbs.

Pull:
5x5 deadlift 305 and progressing weekly 10lbs still nicely,
3x5 weighted pull ups 30lbs and 1 set AMRAP, 
3x5 barbell rows 190,
3x10 dumbbell row 95lbs,
3x10 shrugs 305,
3x10 dumbbell facepulls,

Legs: simple but ass kicking
255lbs 1 repemom 25 minutes (still progressing 5lbs a week nicely but tough)  close to ass to grass form the single rep i notice  is helping me keep good form. Last set i do AMRAP and got 2 reps out  today. 
135 5reps emom 10 minutes

I split this routine MWF and do some cardio  and soon mma training again on TTR
[image]